# How to set a constraint between a platform and a sprite in Phaser 3 with Matter physics

Tags: collision-detection, phaser-framework, matter.js

I am creating a game in phaser that uses some rope-swinging mechanics. When the mouse is clicked, the sprite fires a rectangle that then creates a constraint between the sprite and whatever this rectangle collides with. Right now, the rectangle will only collide with the boundaries of the world for some reason. I have hitboxes for my platforms, but the rectangle shoots straight through them. How can I get the rectangle that is fired to collide with the platforms instead of the world boundaries?

Code:

```
let game;
let gameOptions = {
    gravity: 2,
    constraintSpeed: 50,
    hookSpeed: 50,
    ropeTolerance: 15
};
const BOX = 0;
const HERO = 1;
const HOOK = 2;

window.onload = function() {

    let gameConfig = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
            autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
            parent: "thegame",
            width: 1200,
            height: 750
        },
        scene: playGame,
        physics: {
            default: "matter",
            matter: {
                gravity: {
                    y: gameOptions.gravity
                },
                debug: true
            }
        }
    }
    game = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    window.focus();
};
//Hero size to do calculations
var heroSize;
class playGame extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super("PlayGame");
    }

    preload() {
        //Load background image
        this.load.image('background', 'images/background.png');

        //Load stationary textures for when Spider-Man is not moving
        this.load.image('left', 'images/spiderman/run_left/0009.png');
        this.load.image('right', 'images/spiderman/run_right/0013.png');

        //Load hitboxes and the image sheet from TP and PE
        this.load.atlas('sheet', 'assets/spiderTP.png', 'assets/spiderTP.json');
        this.load.json('shapes', 'assets/spritesPE.json');

        //Load level one
        this.load.image('tiles', 'assets/tilesheet1.png');
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'assets/level1.json');
    }
    create() {
        //Place background image
        let background = this.add.image(600, 375, 'background');

        //Set boundaries for physics
        this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, game.config.width, game.config.height);

        //Create tilemap
        const map = this.make.tilemap({key: 'map'});
        //Load in the tileset used on the tilemap
        const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('Assets_City', 'tiles');
        //Load in the layer named 'Ground' from the tilemap
        this.platforms = map.createDynamicLayer('Ground', tileset, 0, 0);


        //Make the tiles collide
        this.platforms.setCollisionBetween(1, 750);
        //Convert the layer of platforms to bodies in phaser
        this.matter.world.convertTilemapLayer(this.platforms);
        //Make sure they collide
        this.platforms.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true});
        //Label these for rope collisions
        this.platforms.label = BOX;
        this.platforms.isStatic

        //Update the game at 30Hz
        this.matter.world.update30Hz();

        //Get hitboxes
        this.shapes = this.cache.json.get('shapes');

        //Player
        this.hero = this.matter.add.sprite(600, 500, 'sheet', 'run_right/0013', {shape: this.shapes.s0009});
        //Scale him down so he fits with terrain
        this.hero.setScale(0.5, 0.5);
        //Label the body for collisions
        this.hero.label = HERO;
        //Don't want him rotating in the air
        this.hero.setFixedRotation();
        //Set our variable to do calculations
        heroSize = this.hero.width;
        //No hook (start of the hook) to start off with
        this.hook = null;

        //Fire the hook on click
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.fireHook, this);
        //No rope to start of with
        this.rope = null;
        //Listen for collisions with the hook
        this.matter.world.on("collisionstart", function(e, b1, b2){
            if((b1.label == HOOK || b2.label == HOOK) && !this.rope) {
                Phaser.Physics.Matter.Matter.Body.setStatic(this.hook, true);
                let distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y, this.hook.position.x, this.hook.position.y);

                if (distance > heroSize * 2) {                   //Offset so that the hook comes from his hand {pointA: {x: 27.5, y: 10}}
                    this.rope = this.matter.add.constraint(this.hero, this.hook, distance, 0.5, {pointA: {x: 27.5, y: 5}});
                }
            }
        }, this);
    }
    //Method for firing the hook
    fireHook(e) {
        if(this.hook) {
            this.releaseHook();
        }
        else {
            let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y, e.position.x, e.position.y);

            this.hook = this.matter.add.rectangle(this.hero.body.position.x + (heroSize * 2) * Math.cos(angle), this.hero.body.position.y + (heroSize * 2) * Math.sin(angle), 20, 20, '#ffffff');
            this.hook.label = HOOK;

            Phaser.Physics.Matter.Matter.Body.setVelocity(this.hook, {
                x: gameOptions.hookSpeed * Math.cos(angle),
                y: gameOptions.hookSpeed * Math.sin(angle)
            });
        }
    }
    releaseHook() {
        if(this.rope) {
            this.matter.world.removeConstraint(this.rope);
            this.rope = null;
        }
        if(this.hook){
            this.matter.world.remove(this.hook);
            this.hook = null;
        };
    }

    update() {
        if(this.rope){
            this.rope.length -= gameOptions.constraintSpeed;
            let hookPosition = this.hook.position;
            let distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(hookPosition.x, hookPosition.y, this.hero.body.position.x, this.hero.body.position.y);
            this.rope.length = Math.max(this.rope.length, (heroSize*2));
        }
    }
}
```

The code I am trying to replicate is https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2019/03/08/fling-unity-game-built-in-html5-with-phaser-and-matter-js-updated-with-the-latest-constraints-tweaks-fly-through-the-screen-with-your-ninja-rope/ here, but I couldn't figure out which part detected collisions between the hook and another object.